# Publish the slides file using apps script slide (GAS) service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I need to publish the Slide file to website and get the published URL, But I am not getting the published URL as a return response.

The Drive service is turned on already.

I tried with

```
function doGet(e) {    
  var ppt = SlidesApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1fIQpQJ8QaIqt3fibTGmlAndZuvDG3ry8maAm_0CgSLE/edit#slide=id.p');
  var fileId = ppt.getId();
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId); 
  var items = revisions.items; 
  var revisionId =items[items.length-1].id; 
  var resource = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, revisionId); 
  resource.publishAuto = true;
  resource.publishedOutsideDomain = true;
  resource.published = true;    
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(Drive.Revisions.update(resource, fileId, revisionId).publishedLink));
}
```

Comment: Debugging details? Logs? Timestamp correlation? View> executions?

Comment: Its blank output if I use the above code

Comment: How do I get publishedLink?

Comment: [Edit] to show output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(Drive.Revisions.update(resource, fileId, revisionId).publishedLink)))`

Comment: I see that the json doesn't have the property at all. But the documentation says it has. Any hopes you could replicate the issue?

Comment: [Edit] to add all relevant details in comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### This might be a bug:

The `publishedLink` from a published [Revision](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) (for Sheets, Docs and Slides, at least) is not populated. This seems to be the case for both V2 and V3.

This behaviour was reported some time ago in Issue Tracker:

- [Visible to Public After publishing the publishedlink is undefined](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73536382)

I'd suggest you to star the issue in order to give it more visibility.

In this case, I think a workaround could be to work with one of the Revision `exportLinks` instead.